# zsh: no such file or directory:

Tags: zsh

I have an assignment where I have to use a syntax checker on a python program to see if it's correct. The line I use is:

```
/directory$ python syntax-checker file.py
```

However I keep getting the error no such file or directory:

[image: terminal]

I am supposed to open the python file with the syntax-checker which is located in the directory.

I also have no clue why my terminal looks the way it does.
It says: `fullname@firstname-MBP-2 ~ %` which seems odd. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you type `/theoinf` you're trying to change to a directory that doesn't exist (if you `ls /` you'll notice **theoinf** isn't in the output). Your `mkdir` command was performed in your home directory so that's where the **theoinf** directory will exist. Where you're actually trying to change to then should be:

```
/Users/[username]/theoinf
```

on a mac, or a shortcut:

```
~/theoinf
```

**fullname@firstname-MBP-2 ~ %** is just your terminal prompt showing:

- **fullname -** your username
- **firstname-MBP-2 -** your hostname
- **~ -** the current working directory, your home in this case.

If you don't like the way your prompt looks, I'd recommend installing [ohmyzsh](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh). It has a lot of great functionality and lets you apply a wide range of themes to your terminal.

Also, [iterm2](https://www.iterm2.com/) is a replacement terminal for mac which has far greater features than the standard terminal you get in Mac OS.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation. I just used the ls command and found theoinf in the output. Also when I use the shortcut ~/theoinf I receive the output 'permission denied'.

Comment: Ahh sorry I'm so used to using ohmyzsh now that I forgot to put `cd` in front of the commands, so it should be `cd /Users/[username]/theoinf` and `cd ~/theoinf`. If this is all new to you I'd suggest [going through some of the basics](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_learning_the_shell.php#contents).